# How do I add multiplicity values in StarUML

Tags: database, database-design, uml, cardinality, multiplicity

I am studying Database Development and I am at the stage where I have to create my own ER Models. Everything is fine so far with StarUML however the course notes don't mention how to add muliplicity options between entity types (the cardinality and particpation).

I am hoping somebody could posibly help me here?

Many Thanks
Peter

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. Click once on the line/association you want to add the multiplicity to.
2. Mouseover one of the square blocks at the end of the line so you get the hand cursor and double-click.
3. You then will see a pop-up with a combobox dropdown menu on the right side.
4. Select the multiplicity from the dropdown menu,  multiplicity can be selected from: 0..1, 1, 0..*, 1..*, and * or entered directly.
5. Repeat this on the square block on the other end of the line.